# Why am I getting "Unexpected trailing characters" while setting up Sublime Text key bindings?

Tags: sublimetext2, key-bindings

I'm using mhartl's GitHub tutorial for setting Sublime Text up for Ruby development. I get the following error while writing key bindings for SublimeERB:

> error: Error trying to parse file: Unexpected trailing characters in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap:625:3

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

First off, make any changes to preferences in Sublime Text 2 to your user settings files, not the default files. Otherwise, all of your changes will be overwritten when Sublime Text updates. I can see from your file path that you are editing the default keymaps instead of `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap`.

You can access this in OSX by going to the top menu-bar and clicking `Sublime Text 2` ->`Preferences`->`Keybindings- User`

If you have never edited this file before, it will be empty. Simply copy and paste the following code exactly:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+."], "command": "erb"}
]
```

This is JSON format. Make sure the file begins with a `[` and ends with a `]` as the example shows. If you have additional keybindings, you must put commas in between them, except for the last item.

Comment: tnx for your help !!! I figured it out !!! I'm currently having an error with my rspec !! I can't run rspec true ruby-test pkg for sublime !!! I think this is related to my gem set configuration !! it says it can not load the <require> ed files !!! how can I install gems on a custom gemset and not my default ???

Comment: Put the gems your application needs in its Gemfile, then run `bundle install` in your console while at your app's root folder.